# how to make dynamic color change in table heading in django

Tags: html, css, django

Table heading color not working after 3 class name in CSS, I want to change color when if new data will be added in database after 3 heading how to make it dynamic color change in CSS.

```
<style>.demo1{
    background-color: #F4CCCC;
  }
  .demo2{
    background-color: #D0E0E3;
  }
  .demo3{
    background-color: #EAD1DC;
  } </style>


 {% for i in trades %}
    <th  class="demo{{forloop.counter}}">Capicity</th>
    <th  class="demo{{forloop.counter}}">Total</th>
    <th  class="demo{{forloop.counter}}">Training completed</th>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you need to cycle through  the same colors or a diferent color in each row?

Comment: same color in next cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cycle` templatetag to repeat the same colors: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle

```css
.bg-1 > th {
  background-color: blue;
}
.bg-2 > th {
  background-color: red;
}
.bg-3 > th {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
{% for i in trades %}
<tr class="{% cycle 'bg-1' 'bg-2' 'bg-3' %}">
    <th>Capicity</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Training completed</th>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```